# PHP error uasort()

Tags: php, warnings

I want to install wordpress theme but version php which i have is 5.2.17 so i must rewrite a code:

from

```
// Shortcodes list
//------------------------------------------------------------------
$FIRE_DEPARTMENT_GLOBALS['shortcodes'] = array();

// Add shortcodes
do_action('fire_department_action_shortcodes_list');

// Sort shortcodes list
uasort($FIRE_DEPARTMENT_GLOBALS['shortcodes'], function($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
});
```

to

```
// Shortcodes list
//------------------------------------------------------------------
$FIRE_DEPARTMENT_GLOBALS['shortcodes'] = array();

// Add shortcodes
do_action('fire_department_action_shortcodes_list');

$tmp = fire_department_storage_get('shortcodes');
function strcmp_fun(){
    strcmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
}
uasort($tmp, 'strcmp_fun');
fire_department_storage_set('shortcodes', $tmp);
```

but i have PHP warning in wordpress' debug.log:

> PHP Warning:  uasort(): The argument should be an array in /(..)/public_html/osp/wp-content/themes/fire-department/fw/core/core.shortcodes/shortcodes_settings.php on line 173

What is wrong in above code?

Comment: `$FIRE_DEPARTMENT_GLOBALS['shortcodes'] !== fire_department_storage_get('shortcodes')`.

Comment: notice undefined variable `$a` and `$b` &  `strcmp_fun` is missing a return value.

Answer (score 0):

it's ok? the error has disappeared

```
//$tmp = fire_department_storage_get('shortcodes');
            function strcmp_fun($a, $b){
                return strcmp($a['title'], $b['title']);
            }
            uasort($FIRE_DEPARTMENT_GLOBALS['shortcodes'], 'strcmp_fun');
            //fire_department_storage_set('shortcodes', $tmp);
```